# Is there a way to limit number of selected items that are displayed on a Kendo UI multiselect?

Tags: kendo-multiselect

I have a Kendo UI multiselect that loads approximately 70 options. The requirement is to pre-select all the available options. All this is working from programming perspective. But from the GUI perspective, when all the options are pre-selected, the Kendo multiselect seems way too big on the screen and does not look user friendly.

Is there a way where I can show first few (for example, 5) pre-selected items and then show a custom item(for example, 65 more..)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found what I needed. I couldn't exactly show the kendo-multiselect with a customized item. But, I ended up using **TagMode**. 
Please refer this link : https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/tag-mode

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tagRender` property with appropriate logic inside.

Or `tags`