# Restrict kendo-angular-multiselect to 2 values and add tile button as “5 more” using typescript

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript2.0, kendo-multiselect, kendo-angular-ui

I am trying to restrict kendo multi-select to two values and display a tile button as "5 more" if there are further values.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <kendo-multiselect [(ngModel)]="selectedList" (open)="onOpen($event)"</kendo-multiselect>
    <button class="search-btn"></button>
 </div>
```

list that i am binding will have array of object that i have selected:

main list = `{id:1,"Name":"Wood","Description":"GAS"}
{id:2,"Name":"CHCH","Description":"CTRE"}`

selectedList = `{id:2,"Name":"CHCH","Description":"CTRE"};`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to limit number of selected items that are displayed on a Kendo UI multiselect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521821/is-there-a-way-to-limit-number-of-selected-items-that-are-displayed-on-a-kendo-u)